# Fluttur-Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: flutter

I am creating Product View window in Fluttur and taking values from firestore and want to multiple two values quantity and rate but getting this error

On this Code

Text(widget.number*widget.rate),

Comment: Maybe convert `widget.number*widget.rate` which is an integer to String, like this `Text((widget.number*widget.rate).toString())`. Also, please read [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Text('${widget.number * widget.rate}'.toString()),